# HtmlSelectOneRadio click twice to trigger Valuechangeevent listener

Tags: jsf, richfaces, radio-button, valuechangelistener

I am trying to dynamically create a form which would have a radio button with three choices. The choices are displayed with the radio button but the problem is the ValueChangeEvent is triggered only on clicking the button twice.

My XHTML is :

```
 <h:column>

<h:selectOneRadio id="UserTypeOption" value="#{userRegistrationBean.businessInfo.userType}"
valueChangeListener="#{userRegistrationBean.generateDynamicFormFields}">
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="supplementQuestionForm1"/>
<f:selectItems id="USERTYPE" value="#{userRegistrationBean.userTypeList}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
</h:column>
```

Java code snippet is:

```
private static org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior    
ajaxBehavior=(org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior
) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createBehavior(
org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
static
{ Collection<String> renders = new ArrayList<String>();
ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(userRegistrationBean.getValueChangeListener());
renders.add("supplementQuestionForm1");
ajaxBehavior.setRender(renders);}

HtmlSelectOneRadio radio= (HtmlSelectOneRadio) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(HtmlSelectOneRadio.COMPONENT_TYPE);
ArrayList<SelectItem> radioBtnOptionsList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
radioBtnOptionsList.add(new SelectItem("TEST1","TEST1));
radioBtnOptionsList.add(new SelectItem("TEST2","TEST2));
radioBtnOptionsList.add(new SelectItem("TEST3","TEST3));

UISelectItems radioBtnOptions = (UISelectItems) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(UISelectItems.COMPONENT_TYPE);
radioBtnOptions.setValue(radioBtnOptionsList);
radio.addClientBehavior("valueChange", ajaxBehavior);
radio.getChildren().add(radioBtnOptions);
```

Please throw some light as to why the valurchange event is fired only after the second click. Thanks,GB

I am using RF 4.2, JSF 2 running on Websphere 7 in RAD 8.